# Using ajax to retrieve HTML from the backend then slicing with jquery isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a JS file that requests a HTML file from the backend using ajax which is sent as JSON and then parsed into an object, if i display the HTML using jquery it works fine but if i attempt to slice the HTML and then display it dosent work.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/QuizMaker/AnswerFormGrab/" + QuestionType,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
           if (QuestionType === "MultipleChoiceQuestionRadio") {//QuestionType is correct
                $('#PreviewBody').html(obj.html);
                $('#PreviewBody').find("#Question").html(QuestionInfo[0].Question);
                var QuestionsLength = QuestionInfo.length -1;
                var htmlsplice2 = $(obj.html)//.Slice(1)
                for(i = 0; i < QuestionsLength; i++){//questionlength is 4
         $("#PreviewBody").find("#Question").after(htmlsplice2);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    );
```

If i replace the variable htmlsplice2 which is the spliced html with obj.html which is the html that has been parsed after it has been recieved via ajax it display just fine, i can also use standard html like `<p> Hello </p>` which also works fine but attempting to splice fails.

The html retreieved via ajax is displayed below.

```
<p id="Question"></p>
<div class="row ModalRow">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input AllAnswers" type="radio" name="exampleRadiosModal" id="ModalRadio" value="ModalRadio"/>
        <label class="form-check-label Answer" for="exampleRadios2">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right">Submit</button>
```

I am attempting to slice the p tag and the button tag leaving only the row.

Comment: so adding `.Slice(1)` doesn't work? perhaps you need to use `.slice(1)` instead - but what is it you're trying to achieve using slice? Do you get any errors? Do you understand what `slice` does? `.slice(1)` would get the "second" element in the jquery result ... what is the length of `$(obj.html)` ... is it at least 2?

Comment: oh, you want `.slice(1, 4)` or `.slice(1, -1)` or `.slice(2, -2)`, or `.slice(2,3)` (the last two examples work because there are 2 empty text elements you can ignore)

Comment: In regards to your first comment, im trying to get rid of the p tag and the button, no i get no errors, yes slice removes elements from jquery objects that repersent the DOM i have used slice in other parts of my code and it works fine, ```$(obj.html).length``` returns 5, i have tried all of those slice combinations none have worked the main problem is that the for loop runs 4 times so it should create 4 eleemnst which it does if i use obj.html or standard html but when i use the sliced variable the element is only made twice even if the loop is run 4 times or 8 or any amount.

Comment: I don't get the for loop when you receive one question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: try `$("#PreviewBody").find("#Question").after($(obj.html).slice(1,-1))` in the loop - though, that WILL create multiple elements with `id="ModalRadio"`

Comment: Thanks that worked, but why whats the diffrence between the way youve done it that worked and storing it in a varaible like i did the code is identical. Thank you alot. Hwo do i mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: because lets say `x = $(obj.html).slice(1, -1)`; appending x, you'll be appending the SAME element(s) multiple times - this just moves them in the DOM (that's how the DOM works) ... by creating a new set of elements using slice in the for loop, you create new elements every time (I'm not sure if this is an adequate answer, jquery scares and confuses me)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense i assumed that after was duplicating the variable for me rather than using the same one.